# Insert string("+") into named-range merged-cell but only if empty

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, nested-if

So I have a cell where I'll be putting strings, but sometimes that cell will be empty, when it is I'd like to insert a "+" to indicate that the cell needs a string.

How would I go about this?

I tried referencing itself but that was dumb after thinking about it.

`=IF(ARRAYFORMULA(ISBLANK(MergedCells1)) "+",)`

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bQnGvZw7sTZ5cY1H78bywjqhOs3ceB2bpjuLsCpKklo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tryin A1:

```
=IFERROR({""; IF(A2="", "+", IF(A2="+", "+", ))})
```

then hide row 1

[image]

Comment: I get a circular dependency error.

Comment: @Xandr can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Oh yeah good idea.

Comment: I did notice that whenever I click into an empty cell it triggers this code and my + blinks out of existence until I click off the empty cell.

It's fine for what I need it for, but just thought I should leave this note here for anyone else who stumbles across this.

Comment: It also generates up to 573 extra rows when it triggers.